# VSTO - When get Outlook accounts list from NameSpace.Accounts it returns cached data

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm working on a plugin for Outlook. I need to always have an up-to-date list of Outlook accounts (File->Add Account), but when I take this data from NameSpace.Accounts, they are relevant only at the time Outlook starts. If I add another account or delete the old one, these changes will not be reflected in NameSpace.Accounts. Is there any way to refresh this data?

I am using the following code to get accounts

```
var outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
var accounts = outlookObj.Application.Session.Accounts;
foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: When i check Accounts with IOlkAccountManager it returns relevant accounts. But for me is important to use VSTO entities, because i will to work with DeliveryStore and other relative entities.

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide any events for that. Try using the `StoreAdd` event as a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use `new Outlook.Application()` in an addin - an instance of the `Application` object is provided to your addin on startup, and it is not handicapped by the security prompts..

Also try to avoid caching/keeping a reference to the `Accounts` or `Account` object.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOAccounts](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) collection (which is never cached) and, unlike the [Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.accounts) collection in OOM, also exposes [events](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm#events) when accounts are added/deleted/modified/rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide such events for accounts. But you may try to handle the [Stores.StoreAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.stores.storeadd) event which is fired when a `Store` has been added to the current session either programmatically or through user action.

Note, as a possible workaround you may consider using a third-party library such as `Redemption` which [can monitor changes to Accounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm#events) in Outlook.

There is no need to create a new Application instance in the code:

```
var outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
```

Instead, in VSTO based add-ins you need to use the `ThisAddin` class where the `Application` property is provided out of the box.

Comment: Thanks you, I think Stores can helps me to solve my problem and use VSTO entities.